# App served up to port 5000 "can't be found" on Chrome running on Windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, localhost

I’m a nw to the Windows 10 development environment and have cloned a git repository for a Python + JavaScript project I created on my Linux machine.

I set up the environment and have the script running and via a few diagnostics have confirmed it is being served up to port `5000`. However, when I navigate to `localhost/5000` in Chrome it says:

> “This localhost page can't be found.”

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! This seems so basic, but it turns out I'd typed localhost/5000 instead of localhost:5000. Oops!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/860804)

Comment: @PeterH: (1) Why do you say that this isn’t an answer to the question? (2) Did you notice that the author of the answer ***is*** the author of the question?